# Javascript Variables - Select and Mix

Tags: javascript

I have two to three variables that I want to mix into strings and then place them all into a table, however I can't figure out how to make the variables mix.

What I have is

```
 document.write('<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">')

 var a = ["String1", "String2"]
 var n = ["string3", "String4"]

 for(var i=0; i <a.length; i++){
    document.write('<tr'>
    document.write('td' + (a[i]) + (b[i]) +'</td>')
    document.write('</td>')

}
document.write('</table>')
```

This does create the table I want however it doesn't perform the function I am looking for.

It creates a table that goes:

"string1" "string3"

"string2" "string4'

I'm looking for:

"string1" "string3"

"string1" "string4"

"string2" "string3"

"string2" "string4"

Hopefully that makes sense. I've tried searching through the internet and on Stack Overflow to no avail. How would I make this happen? Eventually the arrays should be able to grow to maybe a hundred each...

Comment: You need a nested loop. The outer loop iterates over one array and the inner over the other.

Comment: Typo: "var n = ..." instead of "var b = ..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an additional loop -

```
for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
        document.write('<tr'>);
        document.write('<td>' + a[i] + b[j] + '</td>');
        document.write('</td>');
    }
}
```

P.S.: Do you really need to create elements using `document.write`? It's OK if it's an example, but this style of element creation is strongly discouraged in real development code.

Comment: I have no idea how to properly create the elements. I'm a complete noobie when it comes to javascript. What is the proper method? I learned all of the javascript I knew from either fiddling with jquery plug ins or Codecademy.

Comment: @PatrickCauley: Almost every one of us created elements in this way when they started, so you have nothing to worry. Check out this [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement) method.

Comment: @PatrickCauley: [jQuery](http://jquery.com) also makes this kinds of stuff really easy. You can check it out.

Comment: I plan on learning more jQuery as well but since it's based on Javascript I wanted a good foundation in pure js first.

Comment: if I wanted to do a character check and not log it if its too long where would I put the if statement? 

My end result is something along the lines of "Standard string of test +a[i] + b[j] + more text"

Before adding a cell I want it to read the length of the string and not log it if it's longer than a set amount of characters.

Comment: @PatrickCauley: Create a variable and assign the concatenated string to it. Then simply check its length. If it goes over the limit, don't print the `td`. I think you should put it just after the first `tr` print.

Comment: So it would be

    var c = (a[i].length + b[j].length)

and then 

document.write('<tr>')
if(c<30){
document.write('td') etc?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36134/discussion-between-patrick-cauley-and-sayem-ahmed)

Answer (score 0):

```
document.write('<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">');

var a = ["String1", "String2"]; 
var b = ["string3", "String4"];

for(var i=0; i <b.length; i++){
    for (var j=0;j<a.length;j++){
        document.write('<tr>');
        document.write('<td>' + (a[i]) + (b[j]) +'</td>');
        document.write('</td>');
    }
} 

document.write('</table>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.write('<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">');

var a = ["String1", "String2"];
var n = ["String3", "String4"];

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
{
    for (var j = 0; j < n.length; j++)
    {
        document.write("<tr>");
        document.write("<td>" + a[i] + "</td><td>" + n[j] + "</td>");
        document.write("</tr>");
    }
}
document.write("</table>");
```

Basically, you need to read the entire **n** array for every element from the **a** array.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working solution after fixing a lot of syntax errors:

```
document.write('<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">')

var a = ["String1", "String2"]
var n = ["string3", "String4"]

for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
  for (x=0;x<n.length;x++) {
    document.write('<tr>')
    document.write('<td>' + (a[i]) + (n[x]) +'</td>')
    document.write('</tr>')
  }
}
document.write('</table>')
```

Comment: Semicolons aren't necessary in javascript a lot of the time. It is so much better practice of course, but the above is an example script and works (paste in the console and see).